# How to convert mp3 to wav with specific options?

Tags: audio, mp3, wav

I need to convert mp3 files to 8KHz PCM-code 64Kbps bitrate wav file. Is this possible with lame or mpg123, or any other programmes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/). It's a free audio editing program that runs on Windows/Mac/Linux.

From poking around in the formats that you can export, if you save as type **Other uncompressed files** and select **Options**, you have the ability to select a WAV file Unsigned 8 bit PCM encoding which I believe is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

mpg123:

```
mpg123 --wav test.wav --8bit --rate 8000 --mono test.mp3
```